# BlueZ: Change local storage directory

Tags: bluez

By default, BlueZ stores its persistent data in /var/lib/bluetooth. This includes controller settings and information about paired devices. However, I'm working in a system where the /var directory is unreliable, so I wonder if there is any way I can change this directory?

I have seen examples where it can be changed during installation, with the "--localstatedir" flag, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require reinstallation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without reinstalling its not possible. Path is configured at compile time so recompilation and installation is required. You can replace STORAGEDIR macro with string which is read from main.conf to different path at runtime. After modifying these changes you can restart bluetoothd every time you change path then it works.

Comment: Would a simple symlink help here if you have a readonly filesystem and want to store bluez stuff somewhere else?

Comment: Symlinking does not work for me. The service fails with the error "Not a directory". Is there another way to remap the /var/lib/bluetooth? Or can I persuade bluez to write to that destination even if it is a symlink?